# python requests post method results inconsistent

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, postman

**Problem**:
Response when using python `requests` and chrome's postman are not consistent for the same request.

**things to note**:
1) url is on https.
2) json is the data format for both request and response
3) python version 3.x
4) `requests` version 2.2

**python code**:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(self.__url, data=jsonpickle.encode(apiContractObject), headers=headers, verify=True)
print(response.text)
```

**response in python code**

```
{
  "productId": 0,
  "productName": "testingPy",
  "yearsArray": [
    {
      "key": 0,
      "value": {
        "outgo": 100.0,
        "benefit": 0.0,
        "net": -100.0,
        "year": "2017-2018",
        "age": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**response in postman for same request**

```
{
  "productId": 0,
  "productName": "testingPy",
  "yearsArray": [
    {
      "key": 0,
      "value": {
        "outgo": 100,
        "benefit": 0,
        "net": -100,
        "year": "2017-2018",
        "age": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "key": 1,
      "value": {
        "outgo": 0,
        "benefit": 110.39,
        "net": 110.39,
        "year": "2018-2019",
        "age": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**the difference**
The `yearsArray` *has 1 element in python code's response* but *actually should have 2* as seen in the postman response

I'm a newbie to Python!

EDIT:
the `apiContractObject` is this python class:

```
class FDCashflowContract:
    """Contract object for API"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.projectionType = 0
        self.isCumulative = 0
        self.dateOfDeposit = ''
        self.depositHolderDob = ''
        self.depositDuration = DepositDuration(0, 0, 0)
        self.depositAmount = 0
        self.compoundingFrequency = 0
        self.interestPayOutFrequency = 0
        self.interestRate = 0,
        self.doYouKnowMaturityAmount = True
        self.maturityAmount = 0
        self.doYouKnowInterestPayOutAmount = True
        self.interestPayOutAmount = 0
        self.firstInterestPayOutDate = ''
        self.productName = 'testingPy'

    class DepositDuration:
        """A class that represents the duration object for use as a contract object"""
        def __init__(self, years, months, days):
            self._years = years
            self._months = months
            self._days = days
```

but the instance that is passed is this:

```
duration = finfloApiModel.DepositDuration(1, 0, 0)

contract = finfloApiModel.FDCashflowContract()
contract.depositAmount = 100
contract.depositDuration = duration
contract.interestRate = 10
contract.dateOfDeposit = '05-12-2017'
contract.depositHolderDob = '04-27-2017'
contract.isCumulative = 1
contract.projectionType = 1
```

this is postman request:

```
{
  "productId": 0,
  "projectionType": 1,
  "productName": "testingPy",
  "isCumulative": 1,
  "dateOfDeposit": "2017-05-12T06:26:45.239Z",
  "depositHolderDob": "2017-05-12T06:26:45.239Z",
  "depositDuration": {
    "years": 1,
    "months": 0,
    "days": 0
  },
  "depositAmount": 100,
  "compoundingFrequency": 0,
  "interestPayOutFrequency": 0,
  "interestRate": 10,
  "doYouKnowMaturityAmount": false,
  "maturityAmount": 0,
  "doYouKnowInterestPayOutAmount": false,
  "interestPayOutAmount": 0
}
```

Comment: What parameters are you passing?

Comment: The answer almost definitely lies in the parameters you're passing to the request. Could you post that as well?

Comment: @mohammad parameter information added to the question

Comment: @Ray parameter information added to the question

Comment: I'm seeing the depositHolderDob having different values in python and postman..

Comment: @Ray the model that generates the results does not consider that attribute of the input in this case. It is most definitely not that that is causing this. I tested another case with the durarion.years as 5 which should generate 6 elements in the array but still contains only 1

Answer (score 0):

**Fundamentally**: The problem as @Ray & @mohammed suggested was the request. The REST service is written on ASP.NET Web API 2 platform and the model binder on the REST controller expects the request object (JSON) to be exactly of the same structure and spelling as the model that is expected to it as input.

**Problem identified**: The problem in the Python request was that the `DepositDuration` object's attributes `Years`, `Months` and `Days` were preceded with `_` and weren't binding and defaulting to zeroes on the api which was rightly responding with an appropriate response.

```
class DepositDuration:
        """A class that represents the duration object for use as a contract object"""
        def __init__(self, years, months, days):
            self._years = years
            self._months = months
            self._days = days
```

**Solution**: I've removed the `_` from the python class DepositDuration's attributes `years`, `months` and `days` and voila everything works!

```
class DepositDuration:
        """A class that represents the duration object for use as a contract object"""
        def __init__(self, years, months, days):
            self.years = years
            self.months = months
            self.days = days
```